# GWT: Add an image to Anchor

Tags: gwt, anchor

How is it possibe to add an image to an Anchor element ? I tried a solution found [here](http://peyotest.blogspot.de/2012/01/gwt-anchor-image-link.html) but still have the target URL text displayed alongside the image. Any ideas ? Thank you. I use GWT 2.5.1.

Comment: Just deleted my answer because it wasn't as useful as I thought :-) What about the public Anchor(SafeHtml html, String href) contructor?

Comment: I created the anchor: Anchor anchor = new Anchor("", "http://toto.com", "_blank"); Then I add the image to the anchor: anchor.getElement().appendChild(myImageInstance.getElement()); And it worked :)

Comment: Glad you worked it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me and that opened a link in a new tab:

```
Image image = new Image("path/to/your/image.png");
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("", "http://your-fancy-url.com", "_blank");
anchor.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Style.Cursor.POINTER);
anchor.getElement().appendChild(mylo.getImage().getElement());
```

Thank you to Sebastian and [peotest](http://peyotest.blogspot.de/2012/01/gwt-anchor-image-link.html) help.

Comment: This approach works; It allows you to use an ImageResource with explicit dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Anchor("<img src=\"path/to/your/image.png\">", true, "http://example.com", "_blank");
```

Comment: How would this approach work with an ImageResource that needs to be explicitly sized?

Comment: Something like `new Anchor(new ImageResourceRenderer().render(imageResource), "http://example.com", "_blank")` ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate, Thomas? I don't see how this would allow me to set the image width and height.

Comment: You should use the ImageOptions' width and height then; or use a DataResource instead if all you're interested with is inlining (and these days, this isn't even always a good optimization). Then use a SafeHtmlTemplate to build the HTML snippet safely from the resource's SafeUri, and set the size you need as HTML attributes or a SafeStyles. Depending on your needs though, plain HTML in a ui.xml, possibly injected as an AnchorElement in the owner class might be a better choice.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in "sample.ui.xml" in client package

```
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
    <g:Anchor ui:field="myAnchor"></g:Anchor>
</g:FlowPanel>
```

write this code in "sample.java" in client package

//declare the variable

```
@UiField
Anchor myAnchor;
```

//inside the contractor

```
myAnchor.setHref("http://google.com");
myAnchor.setText("Google");
myAnchor.setHTML("<img src='google.png'>"); // place google.png file in GWT project war folder (war/google.png) 
myAnchor.setTitle("Google");
myAnchor.setVisible(true);
```

this will give the image with anchor tag(hyper link) GWT project